# How do you say 'set 'or 'fixed' for this example

Tags: word-requests

For example, a person's destiny is fixed/set from birth.

Don't suppose 決定 is the word?

Answer (score 3):

guess it depends on sentences. 
if you wanna say 'a person's destiny is fixed/ set from birth.' in Japanese 「人の運命は決まっている」, as such 決まっている is the way you would take, but don't ask me why it is present progressive form of the verb 決まる.

a verb 決定する means 'deside/ make a decision', hence it don't seem to quite fit the sentence above.

of course there is some words we convey the meaning of 'set/fixed'. for instance, 固定する means 'fix/ set', which is basically used when some sort of smaller parts are physically attached to something bigger part as in 屋根を固定する in Japanese.

check out here.
https://thesaurus.weblio.jp/content/%E6%B1%BA%E5%AE%9A%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B

Comment: この「～ている」は現在完了の意味です。 https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3122/5010

Comment: you are right, thanks. with a little bit more of consideration, 「～ている」expresses   present perpfect, not present progressive.